# Closing tab in selenium is making current_window_handle = NoneType, even when there is another tab open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

As the title says, I'm having an issue where I have two tabs opened, trying to close all but 1 of them, and as soon as I close a tab, the `current_window_handle` value gets deleted. However, I do notice there is still my window handle in the `window_handles` list. Wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue as well.

The code in question:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://example.com')
browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
window_id = browser.window_handles[-1]
browser.switch_to.window(window_id)
browser.close()
browser.get('https://google.ca')
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
```

```
selenium==3.141.0
chrome=93.0.4577.63
ChromeDriver=93.0.4577.63
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Just add

```py
window_id = browser.window_handles[0]
browser.switch_to.window(window_id)
```

to reset the `current_window_handle` property.

So now the code is

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://example.com')
browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
window_id = browser.window_handles[-1]
browser.switch_to.window(window_id)
browser.close()
window_id = browser.window_handles[0]
browser.switch_to.window(window_id)
browser.get('https://google.ca')
```